# Extra Top Bar Big Sur Theme

Tags: software-installation, graphics, kde, themes, 22.04

I have tried to install Big Sur theme on KDE Plasma, but as I showed in the photos there is an extra top bar that I did not figure out how to fixed.

Examples:

[image]

[image]

My Goal

[image]

My Version is Ubuntu 22.04

Here is my guide to install https://youtu.be/DX_gQTQLUZc

Comment: Can you please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1421347/edit) your question and show us what instructions you are following to install the Big Sur theme pack?  Thank you!

Comment: Ah, I see it.  I think all you need to do is turn off the title bar of Firefox.  See:  https://askubuntu.com/a/1288663/231142

Comment: Or turn off any application that has that title bar turned on.

Comment: Thank you, I have search the internet but seems there are no other solitions for total. Maybe editting the whole theme. Probably I'll do it for each app.